# How to convert amazon aws subdomain into new format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The default endpoint & URL for an AWS hosted website is `http://*username*.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html`

But I have seen some like this https://s3.amazonaws.com/*username*/index.html

how do you do this?

Comment: The identifier is not a username, it is the name of the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2):

You can always access an s3 hosted resource at:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket name>/<resource key (usually a filename)>
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 for free-dom's answer...

...but even cooler is that you can use your own host/domain to access the content of the bucket.

**Step 1.** Create a bucket named, say, img.example.com, where you control the DNS for that domain.

**Step 2.** Add a CNAME entry in DNS that maps img.example.com to s3.amazonaws.com.

**Step 3.** There is no Step 3.

You can then access the files in that S3 bucket using http://img.example.com/FILENAME

This protects you in the event you want to change where your files are hosted to somewhere other than S3 (e.g., Amazon CloudFront CDN or another provider).